# How to get tamper status of NFC chip using IOS

Tags: ios, nfc, core-nfc

I am trying to figure out how to read the tamper status of ntag213 tt chip using CoreNFC but with no success, is there any way to send custom command?

Comment: NTAG 213 card's don't have any tamper status? Or do you mean check the "Originality signature" to check it is an original card not a cloned card?

Comment: It is "NTAG 213 TT" not NTAG 213 which is an extended chip with tamper feature, I just don't know the command code I should send to get the tamper status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command code is in the datasheet

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT2H1311TT.pdf

Command is `A4`

You should be able to use the `sendMiFareCommand`  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcmifaretag/3043838-sendmifarecommand to read the Tamper Status