# How to read the tamper status from a NTAG 213 TT nfc using swift

Tags: ios, swift, nfc, mifare

im trying to read the tamper status from a NTAG 213 TT nfc.
I've check this [enter link description here][1].

Every time i do a sendMiFareCommand i get an error "Tag is not connected". I can read the tag using an app called NFC tools and it shows the tamper status just fine.

This is my code:

```
guard tags.count > 0,
              let tag = tags.first
        else {
            session.invalidate()
            return
        }
        print("asd tags count \(tags.count) isAvailable \(tag.isAvailable)")
        switch tag {
        case .miFare(let miFareTag):
            print("asd family \(miFareTag.mifareFamily)")
            let readBlock4: [UInt8] = [0xA4, 0x00]
            print("asd 1")
            if #available(iOS 14, *) {
                print("asd 2")
                miFareTag.sendMiFareCommand(commandPacket: Data(readBlock4)) { (result: Result<Data, Error>) in
                            print("asd \(result)")
                    
                            switch result {

                            case .success(let response):
                                print("asd bem aqui 1 \(response)")
                            case .failure(let error):
                                print("asd 1 Read tag error: \(error.localizedDescription). Please try again.")
                            }

                        }

                    } else {
                        print("asd 3")
                        miFareTag.sendMiFareCommand(commandPacket: Data(readBlock4)) { (response: Data, optionalError: Error?) in
                            guard let error = optionalError else {
                                print("asd deu bem aqui 2")
                                return
                            }
                           print("asd 2 Read tag error: \(error.localizedDescription). Please try again.")

                        }

                    }
            print("---")
```

Thanks for the help.
[1]: [How to get tamper status of NFC chip using IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63627975/how-to-get-tamper-status-of-nfc-chip-using-ios)

Comment: You seem to be sending the wrong command of `0xff, 0x00` instead of the Tamper Status command of `0xA4, 0x00` as per the datasheet

Comment: @Andrew This is 100% my bad. I had the 0xff just in order to get a different error but it didn't work. Originally i had 0xA4 and 0x00 and it didnt work. (i edited the original post to change the ff to A4)